# Is it normal for actors to name their characters?

Tags: character

In [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/why-did-will-smith-use-his-actual-name-in-the-fresh-prince-of-bel-air?s=2%7C58.0126) it says Will Smith named his character because, if people were going to remember his character's name then it may as well be the same of his work...

> Alfonso remarked that Will had to be careful in naming his character,
>   as people would refer to him in public by that name for the rest of
>   his life, and suggested that he name the character "Will Smith".

I thought that most shows created a character and then sought a cast who could play them. Is it common for cast members to name their own characters?

Comment: It seems to me that it is commonplace for stand-up comedians who get a TV show "based on their work" (*at least* first name, if not both)... I have no idea if this was the case for Smith with Fresh Prince, though.

Comment: This is too broad TBH. We can answer *specifically* regarding Fresh Prince but otherwise...nah!

Comment: In some cases, the writer/director changes the character names to fit the actor.  I can't for the life of me remember it, but one movie I've seen actually had every character's first name match the name of the actor playing them.  That's either an amazing coincidence, or a script rewrite.

Comment: Alfonso.... Oh! You mean Carlton?

Comment: @JohnnyBones Probably not the one you're remembering, but the supporting marine characters in Aliens shared first names (or at least first initials) with their actors. In dialogue they're all referred to by last name so it isn't obvious, but you can see several names in their helmet-cam displays: Al Matthews' character is "Apone A.", Mark Rolston is "Drake M.", Cynthia Scott is "Dietrich C.", etc.

Comment: This could be a 90s trend given that [Ellen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellen_(TV_series)) happened in the same decade.

Comment: Ray from *Everybody Loves Raymond*, Jerry from *Seinfeld* and Tim from *Home Improvement* also indicate this was a 90s trend

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is extremely rare for actors to get to name their characters. *The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air* is the exception. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fresh_Prince_of_Bel-Air), NBC approached Will Smith, who was already a popular rapper. Since this would be a flagship project featuring him, he was involved in the development of the project - including selecting his character's name.

Comment: I wonder if he used another name during his rap career, if he would have asked to use *that* name, "Will Smith", or whatever the writers had in mind.  Another note is Jazzy Jeff kept his name ("Jazz") in the show too.  So, in a weird way, you could watch *Fresh Prince* as an autobiographical show about the rapper, Will Smith. ...just with little rapping actually in the show.

Comment: (For interest) Here's a supplementary video from Will Smith himself giving more insight into the process of how he got the role on Fresh Prince: https://www.polygon.com/tv/2018/5/12/17347826/will-smith-fresh-prince-of-bel-air-origin-story

Comment: Note that @Bilkokuya brings into the question if "already popular rapper"; based on the story, he was a one-hit wonder rapper who was down on his luck and about to wash out and was offered the job at a party because someone was drunk and high on coke and thought the idea sounded fun and hip.  No, seriously, watch that video.

Comment: @Bilkokuya - That video is awesome. Thanks!

Comment: I hesitate to put this as an answer as this is "Movies and TV", but it's incredibly common in old British Radio comedies. The main cast of Hancock's Half Hour all had the same character names as the actors that played them: Tony Hancock, Sid James, Bill Kerr, Moira Lister and Andrée Melly. The same is true of Much Binding in the Marsh. Kenneth Horne in Round the Horne, Number 1 and 2 from The Men From the Ministry had the same first names as their characters, Radio announcers also often appeared as themselves such as Douglas Smith in Round the Horne and Wallace Greenslade in The Goon show.

Comment: It's not unheard of though. Janeway (Star Trek: Voyager) was re-named a couple of times by suggestion of the cast. Elizabeth, Nicole and finally Kathryn. Stating it's "exteremely rare" is massively overdoing it IMO.

Comment: @Mast Maybe I did overstate how rare it is. I'd love to see some statistics that show how often an actor has an influence on the writing or development. Within that small percentage of productions, I'd love to see how many of the actors thought that changing the character's name was important. It _seems_ like it would be a really really low percentage!

Comment: I doubt anyone has put together such statistics, but you got me interested.

Comment: @Mast It's got me interested too, but I bet that info has never been compiled!

Comment: Interesting.  Another NBC show (The Office (US)) has done a similar thing with many characters as well.  Many of the non-main roles, like Phyllis, Oscar, Angela and probably more I can't think of, share a first name with their characters.

Answer (score 18):

It is uncommon, but not [extremely rare](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/90256/5429) as Brett says. [A user on IMDB has even made a list of those kind of shows.](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls034597186/)

Usually the star is already pretty popular before the show begins production, and the showmakers use the name of the star to promote the show.

Comment: I'm more curious about shows which are named after their lead actor, but where no character on the show has that name - Off-hand the one that comes to mind is the Cosby Show.  While both the actor and his character are named "Bill", the character is _not_ named "Cosby" as in the show's title, but "Huxtible".

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That might also be more common than you'd think. Offhand I can think of the Dick Van Dyke show, the Mary Tyler Moore show, and the Andy Griffith show as a couple other examples (although the latter two share the first name between actor and character).

Comment: @Carmeister and Darrel - Four more examples for you: *The Bob Newhart Show* (Bob Newhart plays Robert Hartley), *Newhart* (Bob Newhart plays Dick Loudon), *The John Larroquette Show* (John Larroquette plays John Hemingway), *Ellen* (originally *These Friends of Mine*) (Ellen DeGeneres plays Ellen Morgan). Newhart, Larroquette, and DeGeneres were all well-known when those shows were created for (and/or by) them.

Comment: Wouldn't count _Ellen_ since her last name is not in the title, and the character _is_ still named "Ellen".  _Newhart_ is the best example since the character and actor/title have nothing in common, unlike all the others where they share a first name.  It does seem as though this style of naming shows has declined in popularity over time.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Cosby's character on _The Cosby Show_ was named [Heathcliff ("Cliff")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliff_Huxtable), not Bill so it's an even better example.

Comment: @Jaquez - Huh.  Why didn't I remember that?  I guess the show's been off the air long enough I forgot.  (They don't even play the reruns anymore since he's become such a pariah.)

Comment: If the star is co-producer or executive consultant of the show, technically the decision is made by star-as-co-producer, not star-as-actor : ) So I'd say that "Actors don't make that calls, but people we know from acting often do more work on a movie than just act".

Comment: While we're listing them, *Seinfeld* is the first one that comes to mind!

Comment: @anotherdave Isn't *Seinfeld* the exact opposite of what's being listed? He used his real name on the show.